# Switching Electric Fence Live Wire

Tags: high-voltage

I would like to be able control if the live wire of an electric fence is hot or not using a microcontroller.

Turning the energizer on and of is not an option because it is powering the whole premier fence. The system I am trying to build will be used to switch the electric fence on or off for specific segments.

I have not found anything that can handle the 12kv pulse, I tried a relay but the pulse arched between the contacts.

How do I build a circuit that can switch the 12kv generated by an energizer?

Comment: To properly turn 12kv on and off you are looking at high voltage relays and they are not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

The device you're looking for is a vacuum relay. It has large contact spacing and no atmosphere to strike an arc. They are expensive. For instance, [this eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Kilovac-High-Voltage-Vacuum-Switch-Relay-15-KV-SPDT-Tube-26-5V-15A-HAM-Radio-HV-/271978496164) is about what you want, but they're a steal at $50 each. You can try a lower offer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a relay gap that can isolate the 12kv. The gap between contacts must be wide enough. It may require that you custom make a mechanical contactor. Have a tiny DC motor drive the contacts mechanically. Use an H-bridge to drive the motor current both directions to open or close the contacts. Use a threaded rod screw on the motor to separate the contacts. A servo could also be used. But you need to keep power on it if it has a spring return.